# Django model nullable field error makemigrations

Tags: python, django, django-models, migration, blogs

Hello I'm building my own blog and I've been trying to add photos to my blog posts. For now, I can upload photos to the media/documents folder however I'm having problems assigning these photos to posts.

This is how my models.py looks like

```
class Document(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey('blog.Post', related_name='documents', null = True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    document = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/')
    uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

forms.py

```
class DocumentForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Document
    fields = ('description', 'document')
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def model_form_upload(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.post = post
            form.save()
            return redirect('/')
    else:
        form = DocumentForm()
    return render(request, 'blog/model_form_upload.html', { 'form': form })
```

inside post_detail.html

```
{% for document in post.documents.all %}
<div style="padding: 10px;">
  <p> {{ document.description }} </p>
  <img src=""/>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

...

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <a class="btn btn-default" href="{% url 'model_form_upload' pk=post.pk %}">Add photo</a>
{% endif %}
```

For now, I'm trying to print out the description and then dealing with the urls will be easier. The photos are being uploaded, they just aren't connected to the posts. When I remove the `null = True` I can't pass makemigrations on the command line. Can anyone help me with what's wrong here?

edit: If it helps, the comments class has the same line of code, but still works just fine:

models.py

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey('blog.Post', related_name='comments')
    author = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    approved_comment = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def approve(self):
        self.approved_comment = True
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

forms.py

```
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('author', 'text')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `DocumentForm` has no `post` attribute, so it does not know how to save it.

Add to your `DocumentForm` all fields except `post`:

```
class DocumentForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Document
        exclude = ['post']
```

Then, in the view, do the following:

```
@login_required
def model_form_upload(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            document = form.save(commit=False)
            document.post = post
            document.save()
            return redirect('/')
    else:
        form = DocumentForm()
    return render(request, 'blog/model_form_upload.html', { 'form': form })
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response it works! Any ideas on how to display the image? I need to access the url but how can i do it? the files are currently saved with the same name they're uploaded, should I save them with some kind of format and then pass that in the html tag?

Comment: `<img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }} {{ document.document }}"/>` I tried this to include the pictures but i get a cracked image instead

Comment: If you only want to upload images, you can use `ImageField` instead of `FileField`. And try this for rendering image link: `<img src="{{ document.document.url }}"/>`

Comment: I tried that but it still doesn't show up, and when I click on open image in a new tab, I get a Page not found 404 error? it tries all possible urls from urls.py and doesn't match. I get this message **http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/documents/hummus_1.jpeg** @afilardo

Comment: actually nvm I figured it out, I was supposed to add `from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings` and `urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)` to the urls.py file https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/